# React Native Firebase only fetch data one time

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a problem, I made my app with .once('value', but when I restart my app, the content of firebase is still the same, it didn't update.

Why this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to retrieve firebase data each time you restart your app, you can put the code in a class constructor and initiate the class in your main view, like following:

```
class SettingsStore{
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(YOUR_CONFIG);
    super(firebase.database().ref());
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref(YOUR_REFERENCE)
          .once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            let new_data = snapshot.val();
          });
}

settingsStore = new SettingsStore();
export default settingsStore;
```

Then you can load the class in your main app view

```
import settings from "./settingsStore";
```

Hope this answers your question